# Solving Tree Isomorphism with Hashing

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, tree, isomorphism

Given 2 trees with known roots, how can we efficiently determine whether the trees are isomorphic? We only care about the shape of the tree, not the values of the nodes. If one tree can be turned into the other by renaming its nodes, then the trees are isomorphic. The algorithm does not need to be correct 100% of the time so we can use hashing as long as hash collisions are rare.

Edit: Found solution, removed unneccessary clutter from this post

Comment: If you have two children, then evidently the result is 31a + b.  That doesn't handle isomorphism.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, you're not actually incorporating the actual node value in your hash, which seems kind of important...?

Comment: We want to know if the shape of the trees are the same, we can ignore the values of the nodes.

Comment: Whoops, yeah. Considering the number of children is a defining characteristic of the shape of a node/tree, try incorporating that in your hash method. I.e. init: `long hash = edges[node].length;`

Comment: Also, why do you want to check isomorphism in this way? iterating through the tree takes O(n); as does this, unless you cache the hash.

Comment: Well, if there is a better way to check isomorphism, I'm all ears :P

Comment: Define isomorphism.  If it is the structure as defined in your linked node, then straightforward recursion will compare two in `O(n)` and the only reason to hash would be to speed up many pairwise comparisons.  If you think that things like mirror symmetry result in isomorphism, then you should reorganize your trees in a consistent way before hashing.

Comment: I want to know if 2 trees have the same shape, eg. can we transform one tree into the other by renaming its nodes. If you know a solution, please share it. I don't of any O(n) ways of "reorganizing my trees in a consistent way".

Answer (score 0):

After much work and some help, I came up with a O(n log n) solution which also happens to be correct 100% of the time. It's based on 2 ideas:

**Idea 1:** A tree can be represented as a String that lists its subtrees. For example, a leaf can be represented as "L". A tree which has 2 leafs can be represented as "(L),(L)". A tree which has a subtree which has 2 leafs can be represented as "((L),(L))", etc.. The problem with this approach is that large trees will lead to long, repetitious strings, which will slow the algorithm down.

**Idea 2:** Strings can be indexed in a hashmap. Rather than carrying along a substring like "((L),(L))" we can assign that string an index number, let's say 2. Now we can refer to this subtree and all identical subtrees by "2" rather than using the String representation. Strings are the keys in the hashmap and values are unique integers assigned to those Strings.

Here is the code for building the hashmap from the first tree:

Our first call should be `fill(root, -1, 1)`

```
public static int fill(int current, int previous, int height) {
    ArrayList<Integer> subtrees = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int next : edges[current]) {
        if (next == previous) continue;
        int subtree = fill(next, current, height+1);
        subtrees.add(subtree);
    }
    // We have to sort subtrees for "2,4" and "4,2" to be considered the same
    Collections.sort(subtrees);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(height + ".");
    for (Integer subtree : subtrees) {
        sb.append(subtree +",");
    }
    String key = new String(sb);
    if (map.containsKey(key)) return map.get(key);
    int index = map.size(); // assigning next available number
    map.put(key, index);
    return index;
}
```

We can now call fill for Tree 2 (replace "edges" with Tree 2 information, keep the HashMap as it is). If it returns the same integer, the trees match.

Much credit to http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~smal/files/smal_jass08_slides.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You can also use David Matula's Tree - Integer Bijection, which maps trees to integers.

It is a method to assign each tree a unique natural number.

Here are examples of the first 32 trees:

[image: Matula trees for 1 to 32]

For a walkthrough of the algorithm, see the exercises in this document: http://williamsharkey.com/integer-tree-isomorphism.pdf